# How to avoid init function return None in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python. I have a class called Preprocessor with an init function like this

```
class Preprocessor():
    def __init__(self, mode):
```

But when it's init function is called,
`self.preprocessor = Preprocessor.__init__(self, "prediction")`
it always returns None. Why is that?

I need the init function for nothing other than creating a preprocessor instance.

Comment: It's supposed to; to do otherwise is a type error: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__. Why don't you just use `Preprocessor("prediction")`?

Comment: You're not supposed to call `__init__()` yourself. Python calls it for you.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing what you should do with your class:

```
perprocessor = Preprocessor(mode)
```

init is short for initialization. It is a constructor which gets called when you make an instance of the class and it is not necessary. But usually it our practice to write init method for setting default state of the object. If you are not willing to set any state of the object initially then you don't need to write this method.

self represents the instance of the class. By using the “self” keyword we can access the attributes and methods of the class in python. It binds the attributes with the given arguments.